# Add to Unity rigidbody velocity while ignoring the current velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to add a velocity to a Rigidbody while ignoring the current velocity value, For example I have a box sliding down a hill. If the box is sliding at a velocity of X I want to add Y to the velocity of the box without it accumulating over time. This is a basic graph of what I want.

```
Frame 1> X = 1; Y = 0.2; X + Y = 1.2
Frame 2> X = 1; Y = 0.2; X + Y = 1.2
Frame 3> X = 0.6; Y = 0.2; X + Y = 0.8
Frame 4> X = 0.6; Y = 0.2; X + Y = 0.8
```

```
Vector3 slideVelocity = rigidbody.velocity;
Vector3 poleVelocity = transform.forward * vertValue - slideVelocity;

rigidbody.velocity = slideVelocity + poleVelocity;
```

This is the code that I tried

Which does technically work but stops the box from sliding on its own.

Comment: What is `X=1` ? What's the `1` means? strength? direction? If you have 4 keys to move, e.g WASD, then you have 4 directions: forward,back,left,right. I think you should use Vector/Vector3 to represent the velocity.
And the expr `slideVelocity + poleVelocity` is `slideVelocity + transform.forward * vertValue - slideVelocity`, and it is `transform.forward * vertValue - slideVelocity + slideVelocity `

Comment: Could you add a value that tells the program what y has currently been added, and if you want to change y, you take away the previous y from the velocity and add the new one

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Rigidbody`'s built in methods for adding forces along with the `ForceMode` argument. They are very appropriately named. I'm referring to `AddForce` and `AddRelativeForce`. You most likely want to use `ForcemMode.Impulse` or `ForceMode.VelicityChange` but I can't really know as you haven't explained your use case.

I highly recommend reading the documentation on `Rigidbody` anf anything else you are unsure of for that matter.